# PowerBI Embedded - GetTables results in Unauthorized

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi

Receiving unauthorized as the response when trying to fetch tables within the datasets. I'm not clear on why, given that I seem to be able to get and delete datasets without issue. I did not see a reference in the docs on any special steps to be taken?

I am ultimately looking to manipulate the rows, but the row methods are also being returned with an unauthorized response even when I skip over the table iteration and go straight for them.

method-- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powerbi.api.beta.datasetsextensions.gettables.aspx

```
static async Task GetTableInformation(string workspaceCollectionName, string workspaceId)
{
    var devToken = PowerBIToken.CreateDevToken(workspaceCollectionName, workspaceId);

    using (var client = await CreateClient(devToken))
    {
        var datasets = client.Datasets.GetDatasets(workspaceCollectionName,workspaceId);

        foreach(var dataset in datasets.Value)
        {
            var tables = client.Datasets.GetTables(workspaceCollectionName, workspaceId, dataset.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Table count is {0}.", tables.Value.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the push data APIs aren't supported with Power BI Embedded yet.  The Power BI team will be updating their APIs to reflect that ASAP since this is a bug in their SDKs.